# How to close Slidable automatically in 1 second?

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_slidable and it works well, but I would like to make that when you slide a item, automatically it returns at the original position (close) after 1 second.
And only keep opened when a bool change.
Is there any option or a way to do ir programatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to read the documentation, last section is talking about your need:

> How can I open the Slidable programmatically?
> You can `open` or `close` the Slidable programmatically by calling the open or close method of the `SlidableState`. The easiest way get the `SlidableState` from a child is to call `Slidable.of(context)`.
> The open method has an optional parameter called actionType that let you choose which action pane to open.

> How can I dismiss the Slidable programmatically?
> Similar to opening or closing, you can dismiss the Slidable programmatically by calling the `dismiss` method of the `SlidableState`.
> If you want to use the dismiss method without allowing your user to slide to dismiss, you can set the dragDismissible parameter of the SlidableDismissal constructor to false.

You can use this with `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){ //open or close });`